# How to simulate a local/push notification in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios-simulator

WatchKit allows us to [simulate notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html) with an `.apns` file.

How can I do the same thing in an iOS app? (Preferably in the simulator.)

The reason I ask is that I want to have the debugger active when the app is initially launched via a notification (i.e. I want to see what happens in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method). If I start a new debugging session it will call application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: immediately, and then I can never test that code path when I tap on the notification.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to simulate a notification in the simulator. You can debug to a real device and send a sandbox push notification to hit that function in Xcode.