# How do you use Notification Simulation Files in XCode?

Tags: ios, mobile, push-notification

I noticed in XCode that you can create Notification Simulation Files when you go to File -> New File -> Resource -> Notification Simulation File. It creates a file with an .apns extension.

How do I get my app to consume this file and simulate a push notification?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate a local/push notification in iOS simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864651/how-to-simulate-a-local-push-notification-in-ios-simulator)

Comment: Is this only for Apple Watch?